# Solving $-2y'=xy^3+y$ with an initial value

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a bit of trouble with this differential equation and it's initial value:

The equation itself is $-2y'=xy^3+y$, and the initial value $y(1)=0$

I solved it using Bernoulli's equation:

Let $z=y^{-2}$ then $z'=-2y^{-3}y'$ so, $y'=\frac{z'}{-2y^{-3}}$

Using that change of variables, I get $z'=x+z$, and solving that diff eq and undoing the change of variable:

$y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ke^x-x-1}}$

When trying to solve for $k$, with the given initial value I can't get past this:

$y(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ke-2}}=0$, and of course there's no $k$ that satisfy this.

Comment: The initial condition is not consistent with the substitution you made for Bernoulli.

Comment: In other words, you assumed $y\ne 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y(1) =0$, the substitution $z = y^{-2}$ does not work.

Indeed, the constant function $y(x)=0$ is one of the solutions. By uniqueness, it's THE solution.